# Laptop crashes as soon as I login as administrator

Tags: windows-7, crash

This has always been the case every single time I start up my Laptop.

Every single time the computer has finished booting up, and asks for my password to start using my computer, the computer will log on as normal. But after a short time, everything just stops, the screen is viewable but frozen. My cursor will not move and the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> key combinations will not work at all.

I checked if the computer is even responding by pressing the <kbd>NUM-LOCK</kbd> key and the NUM-LOCK light indicator will not even turn off/on.

I have tried un-installing a few hefty programs in safe mode to see if it is a start up issue (which I am suspecting it is) but the problem was not fixed at all.

There will be a few times where my computer will not crash at all but when I click the start menu there are no programs detected at all.

I tried running my web browser but instead a window popped up stating that the program does not exist. I do not know what to do. I would love to have it fixed very soon.

Does anyone have any clues on how to go about troubleshooting and fixing this?

Answer (score -1):

some Malware caused that by coping theme selves every where in the disk,
try to:
1-scan your disk for **Bad sectors**  you can use Hiren's boot  under ->dos programs->Hard-disk ->HDAT 
2-scan your hard disk for viruses by Antivirus Rescue live Disk  -generally all anti virus provide it for free- you can uses this

### http://www.eset.com/int/support/sysrescue/

that feeling when i can't express -_-